# Finding $p_{ij}^{(n)}$ (nth step transition probability).

Tags: markov-chains

The question is how do I find $p_{ij}^{(n)}$ given that it's true that $P^{(n)}=P^n$ where $P$ is the 1 step transition matrix, but it's not always true that $p_{ij}^{(n)}=p_{ij}^n$ (according to my notes).

It seems like that 2nd equation not holding implies it is no use to diagonalize $P$ to find $P^n$ in order to find $p_{ij}^{(n)}$.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that if $P=ADA^{-1}$ for some diagonal matrix $D$ then $P^n=AD^nA^{-1}$. However, this need not be true in order to compute $P^n$. Consider

$$P = \begin{pmatrix}
5/12 & 5/12 & 1/6 \\
1/4 & 1/4 & 1/2 \\ 
1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3
\end{pmatrix},$$
then 
$$
P^2 = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
 \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
 \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and hence $$P^n=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
 \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
 \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
\end{array}
\right) $$ for any $n\geqslant 2$.